# Call a python main from another python script

Tags: python

I have been giving some huge command line tool from a colleague. The main reads a bunch of arguments, parses those using the elegant `import OptionParser` later on and does the job.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

I can either dig into the code and copy paste loads of code, or find a way to use a "command line" call from my python script. I guess the second option is preferrable as it prevents me from randomly extracting code. Would you agree ?

Comment: `from another_script import main`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to do cut and paste or launch a new Python interpreter.  You should be able to [`import` the other script](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

For example, if your colleague's script is called `somescript.py` you could do:

```
import somescript
args = ['one','two']
somescript.main(args)
```